# Как отсортировать массив изображений по alt?

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Есть массив изображений, который надо отсортировать по alt изображения.

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
imagesArray.sort((a, b) => a.alt - b.alt);
```

Однако выдает `NaN`.

UPD. Уточняю. Я ловлю DOM-коллекцию через querySelectorAll и преобразую в массив, который мне и надо отсортировать по alt. Ниже пример HTML:

```
<form class="game__content">
  <div class="game__option">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/500" alt="Option 2" width="468">
  </div>
  <div class="game__option">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/305/455" alt="Option 3" width="307.010989010989">
  </div>
  <div class="game__option">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Option 1" width="458">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: добавте в вопрос пример своег омасива

Comment: Ответил на это ниже для adudnik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Решение:

```js
let array = document.querySelectorAll('.game__option img');
console.log(array); // сейчас это nodeList
array = Array.from(array); // делаем array
console.log(array); // теперь это array
console.log(array.sort(function(a, b) { // сортируем 
  if (a.alt > b.alt) { 
    return 1; } 
  if (a.alt < b.alt) { 
    return -1; } 
  return 0; 
}));
```

```html
<form class="game__content">
  <div class="game__option">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/500" alt="Option 2" width="468">
  </div>
  <div class="game__option">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/305/455" alt="Option 3" width="307.010989010989">
  </div>
  <div class="game__option">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Option 1" width="458">
  </div>
</form>
```

### Объяснение:

Я не знаю были ли ошибки с созданием массива (т.к. вы не указали код, который написали для его создания), но `=> a.alt - b.alt` точно не подходит для сортировки строк.

Идея сортировки в том, чтобы сравнивая элементы в return вернуть либо положительное число, чтобы сказать больше, либо отрицательное - чтобы сказать меньше, либо ноль - без изменений. А вы пытались вычитать из строки строку и возвращать результат чтобы он сортировал. Это подходит для сортировки чисел, и не подходит для сортировки строк.

Почитайте, довольно подробно описано с примерами: https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods

Comment: судя по всему там массив DOM узлов `img`

Comment: Прошу прощенья. Да, уточняю. Я ловлю коллекцию DOM с помощью querySelectorAll, затем делаю из нее обычный массив, который мне и надо отсортировать по alt

Comment: @alex вы можете в свой вопрос добавить пример html и js того, как вы создаете массив и работаете с ним? Будет гораздо удобнее, чем играть в угадайку.

Comment: @adudnik.ru на ваш ответ это никак не влияет, ничего не изменится, врлоде

Comment: Привел в самом вопросе

Comment: @alex изменил ответ. Привел решение. В общем-то изначально ответ был правильный, если он у вас не работал - значит как-то не так работали с селекторами/nodeList или формировали массив.

Comment: @adudnik.ru, благодарю Вас, очень помогло. Но не подскажете, что было неправильно в моем изначальном способе?

Comment: @alex я не знаю были ли ошибки с созданием массива (т.к. вы не указали код, который написали для его создания), но  => a.alt - b.alt точно не подходит для сортировки строк. Идея сортировки в том, чтобы в return вернуть либо положительное число, чтобы сказать больше, либо отрицательное - чтобы сказать меньше, ноль - без изменений. А вы пытались вычитать из строки строку и возвращать результат чтобы он сортировал. Это подходит для сортировки чисел, и не подходит для сортировки строк.

Почитайте, довольно подробно описано: https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods

Comment: @alex буду признателен за выбор ответа как решение и "стрелку вверх". Я тут ради репутации профиля.

Comment: @adudnik.ru, еще раз спасибо!